# Migrate sql data in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have two applications first one is application1 and second application1+ and how to migrate the data for application1 and application1+ from these respective old versions to the new versions

Comment: Could please tell us what have you searched towards this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out on first new app start is there an SQLite database with old format of data. If so - just create new SQLite database, get data from old database and put it into the new database. After that destroy old database file.